# Did Joe Sowerbutts re-dub a couple of scenes for Daniel Radcliffe in Philosopher’s Stone after his voice began to break?

Tags: harry-potter, behind-the-scenes

Some sources say that during the end of filming of *Philosopher’s Stone*, Daniel Radcliffe’s voice began to break, so the filmmakers, at the last minute, brought in 13 year old schoolboy Joe Sowerbutts, who also voiced Harry Potter in the respective video game, to re-dub a couple of scenes for him. The two scenes in question were:

- One on a broomstick
- One in the Forbidden Forest.

However, another source says the filmmakers have denied this, saying that they didn’t use any voice other than Radcliffe’s own.

**So what source gives more weight?**

Comment: Wait, really? "Philosopher's Stone"? No way.

Answer (score 14):

### On balance, probably yes he did, but Warner Bros. are sticking to their story that he didn't. Dark rumours abound that his parents were 'gotten to' and the actor has never spoken about it again, even as an adult.

Sowerbutts claimed (in an interview with [The Sun](https://web.archive.org/web/20011110015815/http://www.thesun.co.uk/article/0,,2-2001380286,00.html) newspaper) that he was present at the studio for a single morning and was told that he was doing voiceover work that would be included in the film.

> *"I was only there for one morning at Shepperton Studios but it was great fun. **I couldn't believe it when they told me I was going to be
> in the film.** I was really surprised that Daniel's voice broke because
> he's younger than I am. But you could say it was a lucky break for
> me."* Joe added: *"I'm a massive Harry Potter fan and I've read all
> the books. Being Harry Potter was so cool. My friends, brother and
> sister are really jealous. Everyone is like, Wow, you're playing Harry
> Potter. It's unbelievable. However, **I'm only in it a bit. I've got two
> scenes; one where I'm flying around on a broomstick and another when
> I'm in the forest."***
>
> <sub><sup>[The Sun - Nov 1st 2001](https://web.archive.org/web/20011110015815/http://www.thesun.co.uk/article/0,,2-2001380286,00.html)</sup></sub>

When asked to confirm this, the studio's spokeswoman rushed out a statement to the effect that they didn't use Sowerbutts' voice in the final cut and that Daniel Radcliffe was the sole voice of Harry Potter.

> *"Despite what has been reported, only Daniel's voice is used in the
> forthcoming film. Do you think we would be that silly? Production of
> the sequel is under way and it is absolutely Daniel's voice in that as
> well."*
>
> <sub><sup>[Scottish Daily Record - Nov 2nd 2001](https://www.thefreelibrary.com/HARRY+AND+THE+SORCERER%27S+APPRENTICE%3B+Riddle+of+star%27s+voice+stand-in.-a079641497)</sup></sub>

and

> "*No voice other than that of Daniel Radcliffe's was used to portray Harry Potter in the film Harry Potter And The Philosopher's Stone."*
>
> <sub><sup>[Daily Telegraph - Nov 2nd 2001](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/uknews/1361257/Studio-has-last-word-over-Harry-Potter-and-the-broken-voice.html)</sup></sub>

---

Although the two statements aren't *mutually exclusive* (since voiceover actors are often used in the rough cut and then replaced by the original actor using [ADR](http://tophollywoodactingcoach.com/2014/01/voiceover-terms-whats-vo-adr-looping/)) he and his parents were evidently reminded of the dire consequences of speaking without studio clearance and haven't spoken about it since, which strongly suggests that [we'll never know the whole truth of what happened...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MkMKzdTBEOc)

> **Julie Sowerbutts:** *"We have to accept what Warner Bros are saying and offer a no comment. I've got a little boy who wants to be an actor long term and I'd hate to wreck anything for him. **If Joe's voice was to be in the first film then it was only going to be a couple of lines. Maybe they didn't use it."***
>
> <sub><sup>[Scottish Daily Record - Nov 2.](https://www.thefreelibrary.com/HARRY+AND+THE+SORCERER%27S+APPRENTICE%3B+Riddle+of+star%27s+voice+stand-in.-a079641497)</sup></sub>

Comment: That's a very surprising answer.  If they had done something like that in the US, SAG-AFTRA would flip out.

Comment: "*Dark rumours abound that his parents were 'gotten to'*" - where are these rumours? You mention this in a big clickbaity title, but then don't point to any such rumours or evidence in the post itself.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - In the Scottish Daily Record article; "*However, Joe's parents, Julia and Kevin, hinted yesterday that they had been gagged.*"

Comment: Might be worth editing some more content from that article into your answer?